# Java GPA Calculator for loop using ENUM and switch case

Tags: java

Update: 
Now I just need to fix the loop and the switch method for it to get the letters from the user input and switch them to numbers for calculating gpa.

Previous message:
I am trying to make a simple gpa calculator which already has the courses in ENUM and it would just ask the user for the Letter grade and switch it to a number for it to sum and divide by credits hours already provided on code. No need to enter the credit hours it is already on code. 
I tried to do it but do not know how to change the letters to numbers using switch and I need it to ask for every course. It is only asking me the grade for the first course and would only accept a number answer. Like 2 per example. Thanks. 
What I have right now:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Degree {

    enum Courses {MATH5070, MATH5080, STAT6020, STAT6050, DATA6200, DATA6300}

    enum Grades {A, B, C}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Courses[] grade = Courses.values();

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double points = 0, sum = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < grade.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter Grade (A,B, C) for " + grade[i]);
            points = keyboard.nextDouble();
            // add course grades and divide by credits 3 each course equals 18 in this case
            sum = sum + points * 3 / 18 ; 
            System.out.println("Total GPA points = " + sum);

            {
                Grades Letters = null;
                String answer = keyboard.next();
                answer = answer.toUpperCase();
                Letters = Grades.valueOf(answer);

                switch (Letters) {
                    case A:
                        double A = 4;
                        break;
                    case B:
                        double B = 3;
                        break;
                    case C:
                        double C = 2;
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Wrong");
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please follow the Java naming conventions.

Comment: Could you help me out with this sir? I want to fix this but do not know how to. I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: What you want is to have the number without the switch, don't you?

Comment: Ok, The program will ask the grades for every course. the user inputs the grades on letters not numbers. Then the program will give gpa total.

Comment: User will receive a line for every class with: Enter grade ( A, B , C ) for (Name of Class) : A

Comment: I want it to convert the user input Grade on letters to double number so it could do the math to get the gpa. Also I do not know why my loop is not working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took some time to rewrite your code as clean as possible. I've made various changes that I hope help with simplifying your code. When learning Java, it helps to "mess around" with the language and when you have a question, try running it. For example, try to modifying my rewrite of your code to use your original `Grades` enum in the switch statement instead of Strings.

Below you can see how a switch is used with a String. Enum's work similarly with enums. See the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) for examples.

Some changes:

1. Renamed several variables.
2. Removed both enums.
3. Changed how GPA is calculated.
4. Added a method `getPointsForLetterGrade` for clarity.

The code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Degree {
    private static final String[] courses = {"MATH5070", "MATH5080", "STAT6020", "STAT6050", "DATA6200", "DATA6300"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double sumOfPoints = 0;

        for (String course : courses) {
            System.out.println("Enter Grade (A, B, C) for " + course);
            String letterGrade = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            sumOfPoints += getPointsForLetterGrade(letterGrade);
        }
        double gpa = sumOfPoints / courses.length;
        System.out.println("Total GPA points = " + gpa);
    }

    private static int getPointsForLetterGrade(String letterGrade) {
        int pointsForLetter = 0;
        switch (letterGrade) {
            case "A":
                pointsForLetter = 4;
                break;
            case "B":
                pointsForLetter = 3;
                break;
            case "C":
                pointsForLetter = 2;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Wrong");
                break;
        }
        return pointsForLetter;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks very much this is what I wanted, simple and it works. Awesome! I will keep learning, I am loving how simple java can be.